# finding values of x and y using Octal Base system

Tags: numbers, computer-science, octal

In finding the values of `x` and `y`, if  `(x567) + (2yx5) = (71yx)` ( all in base 8) I proceeded as under.

I assumed `x=abc` and `y=def` and followed.

```
   (abc+010 def+101 110+abc 111+101)=(111 001 def abc) //adding ()+()=() and equating LHS=RHS.
    abc=111-010=101 which is 5 in base 8 and then def=001-101 which is -4
    so x=5 and y=-4
```

Now the Question is that the answer mentioned in my book is `x=4` and `y=3`.

Is the above method correct.If so,then what's issue here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't compare the digits beginning with the most significant digit, because you don't know the carry from the digit below. Also a digit cannot have a negative value.

You can start with the least significant digit, because there is no carry:

```
7 + 5 = 14
```

so `x = 4` with a carry of 1 at the next digit.
now you can rewrite your equation to:

```
(4567) + (2y45) = (71y4)
```

now you can look at the second least significant digit (the carry in mind):

```
6 + 4 + 1 (carry) = 13
```

so `y = 3`, also with a carry of 1.

the whole equation is:

```
(4567) + (2345) = (7134)
```

which is true for the octal system.